# Shared Printing Preferences Fail

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer

I currently have a problem with a printer that is being shared through 3 other computers. One machine is the host and it shares to the others. On one of the computers, whenever I select printing properties to change to grayscale printing, I receive the following error...

```
Function address 0x4f5c80c6 caused a problem fault. (exception code 0xc0000005) 
Some or all property pages(s) may not be displayed.
```

This is on a Windows 7 32 bit computer using an HP OfficeJet Pro K5400 Series printer. I have removed and re-added the printer to the computer and attempted to update drivers but nothing seems to work at getting around this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it fine for the other computers?

Comment: Yes, all the other computers who connect to use this printer have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the HP software and drivers have been corrupted. I would suggest removing the HP software from the machine and reinstall it. HP has a [removal tool](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=mp-49137-1) you can use to make sure you get it all.

Reboot before reinstalling the software and drivers. Also, make sure to get the most [current drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=2511747&taskId=135) from the HP site.